# I don't know how to fix the typescript error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{}'

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda

I am a javascript developer and I am trying to write typescript. I understand the philosophy of typescript where you have to actually declare the types of variables. Instead of a function being `doThis(param1) {...`, you would write `doThis(param1: string) {...` I have this AWS lambda code that DOES work properly. The file is called `app.ts` and it looks like this:

```
import { APIGatewayProxyEvent, APIGatewayProxyResult } from 'aws-lambda';

/**
 *
 * Event doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format
 * @param {Object} event - API Gateway Lambda Proxy Input Format
 *
 * Return doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html
 * @returns {Object} object - API Gateway Lambda Proxy Output Format
 *
 */

export const lambdaHandler = async (event: APIGatewayProxyEvent): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
    let response: APIGatewayProxyResult;
    try {
        const words = JSON.parse(event.body).listedwords;
        let result = {}
        
        for (const word of words) {
            const sorted = word.split("").sort().join("");
        
            if (sorted in result) {
                result[sorted].push(word);
            } else {
                result[sorted] = [word];
            }
        }
        response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: result
        };
    } catch (err: unknown) {
        console.error(err);
        response = {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                message: err instanceof Error ? err.message : 'some error happened',
            }),
        };
    }

    return response;
};
```

The problem is on the lines `result[sorted].push(word);` and `result[sorted] = [word];`, I get the typescript error "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{}'." in vscode.
[image]

How could I modify the code to be acceptable for typescript? Again the code works... I just want to know how to fix this error to improve my typescript.

Comment: I think the problem starts here: `let result = {}`. Since you don't declare any type for `result`,  typescript can't know that `result[something]` is allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting that error is because `sorted` could be any type of value (number, object, undefined, etc) and object's keys need to be of type `string`.

Indicate that the type for the `result` variable is an object with keys of type `string` and values of type `string[]`

```
let result: Record<string, string[]> = {}
```

Now you should be able to access the key for the `result` variable and push words to that array

```
for (const word of words) {
    const sorted = word.split("").sort().join("");
    if (sorted in result) {
        result[sorted].push(word);
    } else {
        result[sorted] = [word];
    }
}
```